# git server read files from it's repo(remote)

Tags: git

I set up a git server and a client, now I can push/pull files form client.

However, in the server's repo, I can't find actual file I just pushed to this remote repo.(it is in the git repo somehow for I can get it from 'git pull').

I wish to user server's repo as my document root, but not way if there is no actual file listed same as client repo has.Is there something wrong or that's just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioned files belong to a branch (although they can exist in many branches at the same time), but repos are not in any particular branch.

You don't switch branches of a repo, for they hold every file of every branch as a reference.

There aren't any files in a repo dir as there are in a regular working copy. If you think about it, it makes perfect sense. After all, which index.html would you expect to find in the root? The master version, the develop? The latest release tag?

You can use a versioned folder as document root,.If you want to have it updated after you push to the repo, the simplest way is to add a cronjob with regular pulls. The pro way, however, is to add git hooks to trigger certain actions when you push.

Comment: seems a good way for the server side update. also it looks like if I could use a non-bare repo for the server side, files could be shown

Comment: I'm not sure you can add a non bare clone as a remote to push to. It's an interesting idea though

Comment: hmm.. non-bare repo seems not working well, server side repo requires 'git reset --hard' to update It's file content to what client just pushd.I will try hooks